# Error al cargar datos a un combobox desde mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, web

Tengo un problema respecto a los datos que no se cargan en el combo box, ejecuto el query en un archivo externo y este es llamado desde otro apartado del proyecto para extraer los datos.

> Código A

```
ob_start(); 

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['permiso'])) {

include_once('../connexion/DataBase.php');

$idCel = $_GET['id'];

$fecha = $_GET['fecha'];

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['idUser'];


$manager = DataBase::getInstance();


if ($_SESSION['id_perfil'] == 1 || $_SESSION['id_perfil'] == 12){


    $sql = "SELECT ma.idMarca,ma.nombre AS nombre, c.razonsocial as cliente, ma.idMarca, ma.logo_img logo FROM Marca AS ma
        
        left join ClientesMarcas as cm on cm.idMarca=ma.idMarca
        left join Clientes as c on c.idCliente=cm.idCliente
        WHERE ma.estatus = 1
        ORDER BY c.razonsocial, ma.nombre ASC ";
}else{

    $sql = "SELECT ma.idMarca,ma.nombre AS nombre, c.razonsocial as cliente, ma.idMarca, ma.logo_img logo FROM Marca AS ma
        INNER JOIN usuariosMarcaAsignada AS ua ON ma.idMarca=ua.idMarca
        left join ClientesMarcas as cm on cm.idMarca=ma.idMarca
        left join Clientes as c on c.idCliente=cm.idCliente
        WHERE ma.estatus = 1 AND ua.idUsuario='". $idUsuario ."' ORDER BY c.razonsocial, ma.nombre ASC ";
}

$rs = $manager->ejecutarConsulta($sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){

    array_push($result, $row);
}

echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
} else {

    echo 'no has iniciado sesion';
    http_response_code(422);

    header('refresh:2,../index.php');

}
```

> Código B

```
$('#marca-tienda').combobox({

            valueField: 'idMarca',
            textField: 'nombre',
            multiple: true,

            url: '../php/getMarca.php',
            groupField: 'cliente',
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            onSelect: function (rec) {

                console.log(result)
                //searchTienda()

            },
            onUnselect: function (rec) {
                console.log(result);

                $(this).combobox('clear');

                //let values = $(this).combobox('getValues');
                //console.log(values.length);

            },

        filter: function (q, row) {
            const opts = $(this).combobox('options');


            //fitro para la busqueda por grupo o textfield

            if (row[opts.groupField] != null) {

                return row[opts.groupField].toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                    || row[opts.textField].toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) >= 0;

            } else {

                return row[opts.textField].toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            }


        },

        icons: [{
            iconCls: 'icon-remove',
            handler: function (e) {
                let c = $(e.data.target);
                let opts = c.combobox('options');
                $.map(c.combobox('getData'), function (row) {
                    c.combobox('unselect', row[opts.valueField])
                });
            }
        }],


        onHidePanel: function () {
            //console.log('el panel se cerro');

            const newValue = $(this).combobox('getValues');

            let optionsValids = [];

            let len = newValue.length;

            if (len > 0) {

                for (let v = 0; v < len; v++) {

                    if ($.isNumeric(newValue[v])) {

                        optionsValids.push(newValue[v]);

                    }
                }

                if (optionsValids.length > 0) {

                    $(this).combobox('setValues', optionsValids);


                }

            }

        }

    });
```

Al momento de consultar la información en mi interfaz el combobox se encuentra vacio, desconozco si es la forma en que procesa los datos, o la forma en que se cargan, si alguien podría y gusta ayudarme se los agradecería bastante.

El proyecto ya está en producción y funciona perfectamente, pero en el modo local (se colocó en modo local para realizar cambios sin exponer el proyecto) no los muestra. Ayuda! y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sí en producción funciona y en local no entonces no es un problema de código, sino de infraestructura. Revisa los logs de error en local, te dirán con exactitud cuál es el problema. Cuando pasas de un entorno a otro puede ocurrir que tus versiones de software no sean las mismas, que los datos no sean los mismos, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, checaré a detalle lo que mencionas, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder, bendiciones.